# Using nginx as a reverse proxy to IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, nginx

I have multiple ASP.NET applications running on a single IIS server with different ports for each application.

I have installed nginx on the same server so that my clients can access all my applications only using port 80.

Nginx is running all right on port 80. My individual ASP.NET applications are also up and running.

I made these changes in nginx conf file

```
    location /students/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:84;
    }
    location /registration/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    }
```

Then I restarted nginx and typed the url http://127.0.0.1/students/ in my browser. Nginx served a 404 page.

I made no other changes to the conf file.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That config looks perfectly correct; we have very similar config at my work, using proxy_pass, inside a location block, without a URI portion, to pass requests to different servers with URI unchanged.

Are you able to verify whether Nginx is entering the location block?

Answer (score 16):

I believe that the problem you are having is related to the start of the URL path. Does the URL `http://120.0.0.1:84/students/` return the page, or a 404? If you are expecting to go to `http://127.0.0.1:80/students/` and see the page at `http://127.0.0.1/`, you will find that nginx does not transform the path for you with this configuration. Rather, it looks for exactly the same path at the proxied server.

You need to put the `/` on the end of the URL in the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
location /students/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:84/;
}
```

This is a subtle but important gotcha in nginx configs! If you don't include the backslash, `http://127.0.0.1:84` will be treated as a server location. If you do have the backslash, it will be regarded as a URL, and it will replace everything in the proxy URL up to the 'location' part.

Comment: If I browse http://127.0.0.1:84/students I will get my page, because IIS is listening on 84. What I want is that if I browse http://127.0.0.1/students then nginx should rewrite the url to http://127.0.0.1:84. Is this possible in nginx?

Comment: @Shuaib I believe this is exactly what happens with the config above.

Comment: i am still getting a 404 page served by nginx.

Comment: **I am going to 127.0.0.1/students**. I do not want to go to 127.0.0.1:84/students ... IIS can server that and I do not need nginx @jwg.

Comment: Are you going to `http://127.0.0.1/students` or `http://127.0.0.1/students/` ? Sorry, StackOverflow removed the slash at the end of the URL, this was the whole point of the question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93178/discussion-between-shuaib-and-jwg).

Comment: Can nginx transform http://127.0.0.1/students/Login.aspx to http://127.0.0.1:84/students/Login.aspx  @jwg ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/students or http://127.0.0.1/students/ both return 404 page @jwg

Comment: Hi @jwg , this may seem off-topic but does `proxy_cookie_path` work on server responses that **only** have `cookie name` and `expires` attribute in the `Set-Cookie` Response header? In other words, the `path` attribute is not specified in the server response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform IIS 127.0.0.1:84/students to nginx 127.0.0.1/students . try below code..

```
location /students {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:84/students;
 }
location /registration {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82/registration;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to use this directive

```
 upstream http://localhost {
     server 127.0.0.1:84;
 }
```

and the same block for 2nd

Comment: Nginx gives me the error ... upstream is not allowed here

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!